# Probability of getting a hole-in-one on round $j$

Tags: probability

Say the probability of getting a hole-in-one is $2/9$ (which means the probability of not getting one is $7/9$). I want to figure out what the probability of getting a hole-in-one at some arbitrary round $y$ would be.

I already figured that this would mean getting the probability of not getting a hole-in-one on all rounds prior to y, and then getting the hole-in-one on round $y$. I'm just not totally sure how to express this accurately.

Comment: This is a usual example of a negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Would that mean that it looks like (1-P(getting hole-in-one))^(y-1) (P(getting-hole-in-one) ?

Comment: sure! (filling characters)

Comment: Is the probability of getting a hole-in-one expressed per hole, or per round? And if the former, how many holes per round?

Comment: It's expressed per round. Sorry for not clarifying that. You can just get 1 in a round I assume.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what round you are playing, the probability (at least theoretically) for getting a hole-in-one should be the same, $\frac{2}{9},$ as you have provided. So without any reason for this probability to be dependent on the round, the probability is by definition still $\boxed{\frac{2}{9}}.$

Hope this helped!